# Where to store uploaded files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have an Asp.net web service and I need to store user-uploaded files. At first I thought of storing them in the App_Data folder, however, I now see that **when publishing from Visual Studio with the 'Remove additional files at destination' option, *it will remove files from the App_Data folder* despite checking also the 'Exclude files from the App_Data folder'.**

(There seem to be workarounds for this, but if it's not through the 'Publish' designer, I'm afraid that at some point the files *will* be removed, either due to human error, or some future MS update that will break it.)

So, I need some folder that is not under the publish path, and yet accessible (to the web app, not to the public), and that will not be auto-deleted.

**EDIT**

This is being done on a web hosted environment, so privileges are limited.

Comment: I assume this is ASP.NET MVC or WebForms and **not**ASP.NET Core**. What is your web-hosting situation? You could store files in a directory that's sibling to `wwwroot` and serve them through your application code rather than directly.

Comment: you have unlimited options for folder names in different places, why `App_Data ` folde, just create a folder for uploads, you may even create separate folders for different types.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be saved directly to a file system. It could be a database or a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) for example. It certainly doesn't have to be part of the application folder heirarchy.

Comment: @Dai I don't think I have access to anywhere but wwwroot. It's on web hosting. But yes, files are all served anyway be being downloaded from an ashx handler.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani But it needs to be not under the application publish path so that publishing won't erase them.

Comment: @ispiro well i meant somewhere outside the publish path

Comment: @itsme86 There's no CMS involved here. As for a database, it seems that it's better to store files as files rather than in a database. The database (MSSQL) that the web hosting supplies does not allow saving as blobs.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I didn't think the app would have access outside it's publish path. I thought I'd need some special data folder. I'll try that. That seems to be the best if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may choose any folder in any path (even in another drive) as long as your asp.net application has privilege to write to it. you may even create a virtual directory for this purpose.

**Edit**

As you are using a hosting environment, I don't know which options they have provided, as sometimes they restrict a lot, however in most cases when you are creating a new website in your hosting environment, you are asked to provide the path something like : `\wwwroot` you may want to change it to something like:
`\somepath\wwwroot` (of course you should create somepath first), and you will have access to somepath too.

Comment: See edit to question. But I might be able to publish to a path within the root, and then access files outside that path, but still inside wwwroot. I'll need to test this.